# How to use bootstrapping and weighted data?

Tags: r, resampling, weighted, statistics-bootstrap

I have two variables that I'd like to analyze with a 2x2 table, which is easy enough.

```
datatable=table(data$Q1data1, data$Q1data2) summary(datatable)
```

However, I need to weight each variable separately using two frequency weighting variables that I have. So far, I've only found the `wtd.chi.sq` function in the `weights` package, which only allows you to weight both variables by the same weighting variable.

In addition, I need to perform this 2x2 chi-square 1000 times using bootstrapping or some resampling method, so that I can eventually peek at the distribution of p-values.

Comment: You might want to move this over to cross-validated, furthermore it's not really clear what you are doing.  So you have two variables data1 and data2, I assume they are binary?  and you are using a contingency table to count the occurrence for the frequency of each pair?    

If this is true how do you apply the weight?  a mathematical function would be nice.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted it in Cross-validated. I do have two binary variables, yes, and I am counting the frequency of each pair, yes. In the past I've used SPSS to apply the weighting, but unfortunately I can't provide the function it uses.